# Is there a way to have an interrupt firing on both PA0 and PB0?

Tags: stm32, interrupt

The language of the PDF manuals is confusing me very much, and googling also got me unsure. Am I right in my understanding that you can only have 16 external button interrupts connected to 16 various pins, and you cannot have PA0 and PB0 or say PB5 and PC5 configured at the same time? So you are basically limited to 16 external buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that number of external GPIO interrupts are limited to 16 and you can't configure PA0 and PB0 as source at the same time.

However, external interrupts are not the only way to read button states. You can implement a periodic GPIO scanning mechanism using a timer interrupt. For example, *keypad scanning* method allows you to scan `x*y` buttons using `x+y` GPIO pins. This method may optionally use external interrupts (x EXTI for `x*y` buttons).

Comment: I couldn't find anything about the keyword `keypad scanning` in STM32 documentation. As far as I understand your proposal, the timer is used to generate an interrupt and sample the GPIO through software (ISR) or DMA. The answer I added uses a different mechanism which I find preferable as long as the corresponding HW peripherals are still available.

Comment: Keypad scanning method is not specific to STM32, so it's not included uC manuals. It's used for keypads with matrix-connected buttons. 4x4 for example. In this configuration 4 pins are output pins and a `1000` or `0111` pattern is rotated periodically. Other 4 pins are inputs, optionaly configured as EXTI pins.

Comment: Thankyou for telling me - I just learned something new. Then I think you meant using the timer for a constant period to shift the output bit pattern, and to poll inputs at the same time. So, I'll keep my answer next to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can divert a timer to get another trigger line from the GPIO to the interrupt controller NVIC:

Find a timer-related Alternate Function at one of the pins (can be TIM*x*_ETR, TIM*x*_CH1, or TIM*x*_CH2 for any free "TIM*x*", but not TIM*x*_CH3 or TIM*x*_CH4 as far as I see).

Configure TIM*x* to use ETR or the respective channel linked to your pin as an external trigger input, and to overflow at the first event (PSC=ARR=RCR=0). Then you'll get an interrupt every time this pin changes.

You can further extend this design by selecting flank polarity and activating noise filtering to your needs.